# Bootstrap 3 modal from footer like the one on Badoo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a Bootstrap 3 modal that opens on the bottom of the page for mobile devices, like the one Badoo is using :) [image]

So fare I came up with this:

```
.modal {
position:fixed;
top:auto;
right:auto;
left:auto;
bottom:0;
}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
transform: translate3d(0, 100vh, 0);
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5degcnq/)

How to make this like the modal on the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code a bit, try this:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Modal test</button>

<div id="table"></div>


<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <ul>
        <li>Add to Favourites</li>
        <li>Skip</li>
        <li>View profile</li>
        <li>Report</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#table {
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid LightGray;
}

li:first-child {
  border: none;
}

li:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

Of course you need to add the appropriate responsive breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks, that looks much better!